# "value used here after partial move" error

Tags: rust

I was trying to implement a singly linked list by imitating rust standard linked list implementation and came across the error when I implement the `pop_front` method.

The code I was looking into from [rust is here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/linked_list.rs.html#155), like:

```
fn pop_front_node(&mut self) -> Option<Box<Node<T>>> {
    // This method takes care not to create mutable references to whole nodes,
    // to maintain validity of aliasing pointers into `element`.
    self.head.map(|node| unsafe {
        let node = Box::from_raw(node.as_ptr());     // 1.
        self.head = node.next;                       // 2.

        match self.head {
            None => self.tail = None,
            // Not creating new mutable (unique!) references overlapping `element`.
            Some(head) => (*head.as_ptr()).prev = None,
        }

        self.len -= 1;
        node                                        // 3.
    })
}
```

From my knowledge, the `node` at line 1 is a `Box<Node<T>>` object which is partially moved (the `next` field) to `self.head` at line 2, then returned at line 3 as a whole `node` object by move also, which should also be a move after partial move and could not compile maybe? But it should works as it's in the standard library.

The code I was writing is like the following and suffer from the "value used after partial move" error. The full snippet in the [playgound page here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6f4bfc647c7c4ca6475d8f7bf5e8b9fc).

```
fn pop_front(&mut self) -> Option<Box<Node<T>>> {
    self.head.map(|node| unsafe {
        // let node = Box::from_raw(node.as_ptr());
        // let node = Box::from_raw(Box::into_raw(node));
        // let node = Box::into_raw(node);
        self.head = node.next;
        node
    })
}
```

Could someone please explain on this and give any solutions on how to fix the error? Thanks so much.

Comment: You could probably implement the features you need without unsafe code. I haven't tried implementing linked lists yet. idk if that's just an unavoidable detail with them, but generally there's ways to avoid unsafe. For instance, sharing references to objects is usually something addressed with smart pointers.

Comment: @Elinx `head` is a `NonNull<Node>`, not a `Box`. `NonNull` is essentially a raw mutable pointer (just one that must not be null). As such, it is `Copy` (aka raw pointers can alias), which is not the case of `Box`.

Comment: @Masklinn Thanks for pointing out the difference between `NonNull` and `Box`, but I think `head` is an object of type `Option<NonNull<Node>` and so is `node.next`, check out the definition [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/linked_list.rs.html#40), two options can't `Copy` to each other right, so it's still a `Move` I guess?

Comment: `Option<T>` is `Copy` if `T` is `Copy`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Copy

Comment: Mandatory reading if you haven't already: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).